# Searching for a phrase in a text file and reading next word in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# programming and I'm a bit overwhelmed by all the tool I can use and I can't find one to solve my problem.

I have a text file with lots of information. I need to find "[PRG]" phrase and read the index number that occurs right after this phrase and than, in the line below I need to skip one word and read the rest of the line.

Here is a sample of text file:

> [TYP] 1001    1
>   [PRG]   **0**
>   name    **Bulka Fitnes 1/2**
>   image   31
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...
>   [PRG]   **12**
>   name    **TOST**
>   ...

What I have to do with that is to assign every name to its number. I know that I can use **File.ReadAllLines** to create a table of strings with each line.
I just can't figure out how to find "[PRG]" phrase, read next word, skip one word and read the rest of the line.

My solution in c++ looked like that and I would like to achieve same thing here

```
void CFtp::GetNamesList(std::string nameTab[])
{   
    int numberBuff;
    wstring textBuff;
    wstring PRG = L"PRG";
    wifstream file(m_localPath + "programs.prg", std::ios::binary);
    if (file.good()) {
        while (!file.eof()) {
            file >> textBuff;
            if (textBuff.find(PRG) != string::npos) {
                file >> numberBuff;
                file >> textBuff;
                getline(file, textBuff);
                textBuff.erase(0, 1);
                textBuff.erase(textBuff.length() - 1, 1);
                nameTab[numberBuff] = convert.to_bytes(textBuff);
            }
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Please don't post c++ code if you are expecting a c# answer. Also, please post whta you have tried in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this helps...

```
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   List<string> ListOfParsedValues = line.Trim().Split(' ').ToList();
   if (ListOfParsedValues[0] == "[PRG]")
   {
      string desiredValue = //ListOfParsedValues.Last() ... or whatever you want here
   }
}

file.Close();
```

Comment: It would help, but I'm getting an error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'". It would be perfect for this file, because I would just read 2nd word from ListOfParsedValues to get index of a name. In the next line I could just do the same thing and remove first word and I'd get a name.

Comment: I forgot to do the .ToList() After the split

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```
static void Read()
{
    string[] myFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\1.txt");

    for(int index = 0; index < myFile.Length; index++)
    {
        if(myFile[index].Contains("[PRG]"))
        {            
            Console.WriteLine(myFile[index + 1].Substring(myFile[index + 1].IndexOf(' ')).Trim());
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Read();
}
```

you can edit the code for example:

- pass the file path to the Read function.
- instad of showing the result you can add the values to List and return the list from the function...

and more...

Comment: I could go with that, but I cannot afford to replace "name" phrase, because in language that names are written some of them contain "name" as a part of the word.

Comment: in that case you can use myFile[index + 1].Substring(myFile[index + 1].IndexOf(' ')) // i will change the example